# Node.js in Parse Server, empty values?

Tags: node.js, parse-server, back4app

I use Node.js in Back4App that uses Parse-server. I'm trying to get a weather forecast from openweathermap.org. But I'm getting an empty return value? I Can't understand why?
When used in front-end with flutter it's working flawless with the same url.

```
var _weather;

Parse.Cloud.define("WD", (request) => {

var http = require('http');

var options = {
  hostname: 'api.openweathermap.org',
  path:  '/data/2.5/forecast?q=Malaga&units=metric&appid=mykey'   
 };

callback = function(response) {
  var str = '';

response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;

_weather = JSON.parse(str);
 });  
}
http.request(options, callback).end();
return _weather;

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not awaiting the request to end and the function is returning before it happens. Try something like this (considering you are using >3 parse version):

```js
const http = require('http');

Parse.Cloud.define("WD", async (request) => {
let _weather;

const options = {
  hostname: 'api.openweathermap.org',
  path:  '/data/2.5/forecast?q=Malaga&units=metric&appid=mykey'   
 };

await new Promise(resolve => {
const callback = function(response) {
  let str = '';

response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
 });  

response.on('end', function () {
_weather = JSON.parse(str);
resolve();
 });  

}
http.request(options, callback).end();
});

return _weather;

});
```

Comment: It works after I changed the const declaration to var.

Comment: My bad. I've just fixed the answer. But do not use `var`, use `let` instead.